# Java FX Loading Root Layout in exported jar doesnt work

Tags: java, javafx

I am building a simple Java FX Application which works fine in eclipse, but as soon as I export it to jar form the Root Layout cant be loaded :/
Code for it:

```
// Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../../../../../resources/de/mattech/finance/fxml/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
```

My Package/Project View: 
The Code above is in the GuiCore class. I Dont get why it doesnt work in exported jar form :/
[image]

Comment: are You using maven project?

Comment: No i just created a local Project and dont use maven. Why?

Comment: beacuse when You use mave, when exporting to jar, maven will export javafx which is external library

Comment: are u exported to runnable jar.

Comment: Yes i exported as runnable jar and it fails because the loader location is  null